# Adding partial views and controller in angular app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I am in the process of optimizing the performance of Angular app. I am using ng-include to add partial views and its controllers. Following is the code snippet

```
<!--show term rule view-->
<div id="showTermRule" ng-controller="TermRuleController as term" ng-if="showTermRule">
  <div data-ng-include src="'/Relevancy/termRule/termRule.html'" ng-if="!isPublsihed"></div>
  <div data-ng-include src="'/Relevancy/termRule/publishedTermRule.html'" ng-if="isPublsihed"></div>
</div>
<!--show function rule view-->
<div id="showFunctionRule" ng-controller="expressionBuilderController" ng-if="showFunctionRule">
  <div data-ng-include src="'/Relevancy/functionRule/functionRule.html'" ng-if="!isPublsihed"></div>
  <div data-ng-include src="'/Relevancy/functionRule/publishedFunctionRule.html'" ng-if="isPublsihed"></div>
</div>

<div id="showQueryRule" ng-controller="queryBuilderController" ng-if="showQueryRule">
  <div data-ng-include src="'/Relevancy/queryRule/queryRule.html'" ng-if="!isPublsihed"></div>
  <div data-ng-include src="'/Relevancy/queryRule/publishedQueryRule.html'" ng-if="isPublsihed"></div>
</div>
```

I have a parent controller from where I am making "showTermRule" variable true and broadcasting an event as follows

```
switch (rule) {
    case "Term Rules":
      $scope.currentRuleDisplayed = 'Significant Terms';
      $scope.showTermRule = true;
      $rootScope.$broadcast('updateTermRule',$scope.profileTree[$scope.currentProfile].termRules,$scope.currentProfile,$scope.profileTree[$scope.currentProfile].id);
    break;
```

The problem I am facing is when I use ng-if in child controller, say TermRuleController, it is not able to catch the broadcasted event from parent controller. As per my understanding it is because by the time I am broadcasting event div element which is adding controller is not getting added to DOM. 
I have tried same thing using ng-show. It is working then but then it is taking very long to load the page. Can someone suggest the right way to add partial views and controller. After some research I have found that instead of using ng-include I can use directive. I am yet not sure about it. 
Also I guess writing service instead of broadcasting might solve the problem but my question is, is it the correct way to add partial views having different controllers?

Comment: Use directives with a template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep in mind when using **ngInclude** to split your templates into partials. Instead of applying a controller to an element in a layout-template, apply the controller to an element in the partial. That way you’ll not need to target its parent’s scopes, coupling controllers together by scope. Here’s an example: Layout.html

```
<div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <div ng-include="login.html"></div>
</div>
```

Login.html :

```
<form-field ng-field-data="{{login.usr_name}}"></form-field>
<form-field ng-field-data="{{login.password}}"></form-field>
```

> In the case above, you would want to handle the login model in the
>   LoginCtrl controller, but the scope of the login partial login.html
>   will be one step deeper. Instead, define the controller on the same
>   level as the partial (see below).

Layout.html: `<div ng-include="login.html"></div>`
Login.html:

```
<div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <form-field ng-field-data="{{login.usr_name}}"></form-field>
    <form-field ng-field-data="{{login.password}}"></form-field>
</div>
```

So, in this way $scope of parent and child controller would be same.
So, in your case you don't have to broadcast an event , it would be directly available in the child controller.

Hope, this articles helps you out from the problem that you are dealing.

Comment: Thanks for this simple solution! I think using directive here would be more appropriate. isn't?

Comment: It totally depends, you can do it in either way.